# Faster to wet cure in room temp?

Tags: curing

Since curing meats had historically been done for food storage safety and without refrigeration -- is it likely that we should be curing outside the refrigerator as well? Will the meat and pertinent bacteria cure faster?

I've been curing meats with sugar, twice as more sea salt, and celery juice. One bulk of pork shoulder weighing about 750g and 2.5 x 2 inches at its cross section, took me 7 days to cure fully to the inside. I know this because I had two of those. I cooked one off on the 3rd night, and it was brown at the center; alarmed at the slowness, I added more salt.

I cooked the second pork butt on the 7th night and it was perfectly through and through. Howevever, the core still had a shade of brown/white. **However**, there were some obvious algal growth around the meat -- hope anyone can share an insight into this as well.